# consulta sum en php - mysql de forma dinámica con parametros

Tags: php, mysql

Una posible opcion para solucionar un pequeño problema en consulta en php con parametros.

Esta es mi consulta.

```
public static function List($id){
        $sql = " select * from ".self::$tablename. " where pack_id = '$id'";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0], new List());
    }
```

Donde mi resultado de esta consulta me trae todos los registros ya que asi lo tengo, ahora lo que quiero es, que me muestre el resultado de la consulta donde sume los valores de la 3era columna (18 y 1,  153 y 1, 62 y 1 ) cuando las referencias sean iguales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo asi quiero obtener.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tomado este ejemplo, pero mi duda es como paso por parametro todas las referencias, cabe mencionar que las referencias no son fijas, alguien puede dar una opcion, se los agradecería.

```
public static function List($referencias,$id){
        $sql = " select sum(valores),referencia  from ".self::$tablename. " where referencia='$referencias' and pack_id = '$id'";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0], new List());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo que utilices un Group By por el campo referencia en tu consulta.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b65cf/3/0